# How to reverse a number using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, reverse

I want to send in the recursion only the number itself and not more variables!!!

so, I made a code that make the operation but I don't have the stop point.

the code:

```
public static int upsideDown (int number) {
    number += (number%10)*(Math.pow(10, String.valueOf(number).length()));
    number %= 10;
    return upsideDown (number);
}
```

Comment: question is not clear,

Comment: Go ahead and use more variables. The compiler won't mind.

Comment: The probkem with passing an `int` is zeroes: if you reverse 1002 you get 21 because leading zeroes will be dropped on the first iteration. Can you use a String parameter type?

Comment: 1002 would not yield 21, it would correctly yield 2001 using his approach (if he fixed the bugs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the digit you are working with in a local variable instead of modifying `number`.

You need - instead of `number %= 10` - to (integer) *divide* by 10 instead.

You need to *multiply* the previously stored digit by *10* raised to the power of `string.length - 1`; you need to *add* the result of this to the return value of the recursive call to `upsideDown`.
Actually, a for loop over `length - 1`, multiplying by 10 each time through the loop would be more efficient than using `pow`.

Exit code should simply be `if (number == 0) return 0;` at start of method.